# How do I get a direct link to download latest VSTS release artifacts?

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there a way to get a link that always downloads the artifacts from the latest release in VSTS.  I have a working build definition and a working release definition that is triggered by the build.  On the release summary page I can find a link to the build summary for the build that triggered the release.  I can get a link to the build artifacts from there.  However, what I would like is a stable link that can be used to download the artifacts associated with the latest release.  Is this possible?

Comment: What's the requirement that you need a stable link to download the artifacts of the latest release?

Comment: I am developing an Azure VM Extension.  Part of that process involves a deployment system that is external to VSTS.  I push a button on a Jenkin's server to deploy.  I would like the deployment button to automatically pick up the latest build from master.  I haven't figured out a way to achieve that without a stable link, other than writing extra code to use the REST API to query for the latest build.  I was hoping that I could avoid that.  Particularly since I do not own that deployment system so customization is problematic at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such link to show the latest build artifacts directly.

But the work around is that you can add a **Copy Files task** in your release definition to download the latest artifacts on your local machine automatically.

Detail setting for Copy Files task as below:

**Source Folder:** select the build artifacts you are linking with, and the format will be `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/BuildDefinitionName`.

**Contents:** `**`.

**Target Folder:** specify a local directory to want to download artifacts, such as `D:\ArtifactsDownload`.

Enable **Clean Target Folder** or **Overwrite**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I saw the Copy Files Task.  Having a link to the latest build would be a great feature.

Comment: Having a link to the latest build would remove the need for redundant storage as necessary with Copy Files.